# Polymer core-ajax inside template (on spa article).

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, single-page-application

I'm following the article spa (https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html)
Everything very ok but when i'm trying to make another ajax on the ajax template (right column). The event polymer-ready is cannot fired . Nothing was rendering but when i test out side spa project that work ok. Anyone got the same prolem ?

Comment: Can you provide the code tweaks you've made? In the demo, there's one core-ajax on the page that controls the loading of dynamic content. The polymer-ready event is something you shouldn't need. That is fired at page load time when polymer has upgraded all of the custom elements on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Everything i extractly like the article. And here is my second page content. Can i use core-ajax again in the ajax content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make another AJAX request to your own AJAX template., append an object with a name, hash, and url to the object, `template.pages` on Line 10 of `app-ajax.js`.

```
// Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/demos/spa/app-ajax.js

template.pages = [
  {name: 'Intro', hash: 'one', url: '/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html'},
  {name: 'Step 1', hash: 'two', url: '/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html'},
  {name: 'Step 2', hash: 'three', url: '/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html'},
  {name: 'Step 3', hash: 'four', url: '/docs/start/tutorial/step-3.html'},
  {name: 'Step 4', hash: 'five', url: '/docs/start/tutorial/step-4.html'},
];
```

Comment: Thanks i got it but i wanna to make a ajax request from intro.html , step-1.html.

Comment: Hey Nhan, just wanted to follow-up with your AJAX request. I checked out the earlier posted test site (seismic-origin.com/test) but found a 404. Were you able to get it working?